# Pressing <Enter> while cursor focus is in a text box should activate a specific button on the form. [Powershell]

Tags: forms, winforms, powershell, user-interface, powershell-5.0

[image: Image of Form]

When a user enters text into one of the search boxes, I would like them to be able to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to perform the same function as clicking a button would.

For example if they were typing in the boxed labeled "Find Username" - they would have the option to either press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or click the "Show Users" button. 
If they were typing in the box labeled "Find First Group" then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> would then be the equivalent of selecting the "Show 1st Groups" button.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: which programming language do you use?

Comment: @MongZhu Powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put in a `KeyEventHandler` to the TextBox

```
$textBox1.add_KeyDown($textbox1_KeyDown)
$textbox1_KeyDown=[System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler]{
    if($_.KeyCode -eq 'Enter')
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Forgot to add the code for associating the event handler to the object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `KeyDown` event of the `TextBox` and check which key has been pressed. Inside the event you can just call the event handler of the button that you which to be pressed.

```
private void findUserNameTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        Show_UsersButton_Click(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```